# Creating dummy variables using pd.get_dummies in a for loop in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, dummy-variable

I want to convert a particular categorical variable into dummy variables using **pd.get_dummies()** for both test and train data so instead of doing it for both separately, I used a for loop. However, the following code does not work and **.head()** returns the same dataset.

```
combine = [train_data, test_data]
for dataset in combine:
    dummy_col = pd.get_dummies(dataset['targeted_sex'])
    dataset = pd.concat([dataset, dummy_col], axis = 1)
    dataset.drop('targeted_sex', axis = 1, inplace = True)

train_data.head() # does not change
```

Even if I use an iterator which traverses the index like this, it still doesn't work.

```
for i in range(len(combine)):
```

Can I get some help? Also, Pandas get_dummies() doesn't provide an **inplace** option.

Answer (score 1):

For referencing purposes , I would use a dict:

Create a dictionary of train and test:

```
combine={'train_data':train_data,'test_data':test_data}
```

---

Use this code which uses a dict comprehension:

```
new_combine={k:pd.concat([dataset, pd.get_dummies(dataset['targeted_sex'])], axis = 1)
                            .drop('targeted_sex',1) for k,dataset in combine.items()}
```

---

Print test and train now by referencing the keys:

```
print(new_combine['train_data']) #same for test
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print `dataset.head()` instead of `train_data.head()`.

You can use this function:

df: dataframe
todummy_list: list of column names which will be dummies

```
def dummy_df(df, todummy_list):
    for x in todummy_list:
        dummies = pd.get_dummies(df[x], prefix=x, dummy_na=False)
        df = df.drop(x, 1)
        df = pd.concat([df, dummies], axis=1)
    return df
```